# Not able to read special character in buffer from http response on DAP

Tags: java

I have a simple http get call from java using simple headers accept type and authorization in header .

“I’m using charset UTF-8” when I try the same code in local that is on IDE eclipse tomcat server I am getting proper response and but when put the same code on dap server response data is getting changed .

Example : Ó (actual data sent by the client) same as is data I am getting in LOCAL but in DAP only such char apart from alpha numeric (Ó) changing to some other char like this Á.

Stuck in this from couple of days .

Please provide me the solution .

Thanks ,
Mussaveer

Tried all charset while consuming input stream .

InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"");

Comment: try ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

Comment: Tried it work well and good in Local but the same code on DAP we are facing issues

Comment: issue got resolved by using a header in request conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","UTF-8")